# special device tmpfs does not exist

Tags: mount, fstab, tmpfs

I'm trying to speed up a project which uses a folder for cache by mounting the cache folder on `tmpfs`. But whenever I mount it I get this error message:

```
mount: special device tmpfs does not exist
```

this is the entry on `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /home/rkmax/Projects/webapp/app/cache rw,size=500M,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0
```

My distro is ArchLinux.

Comment: You haven't specified the filestype in your `/etc/fstab`: see [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#tmpfs) for the correct options...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify the filesystem type - this is required.

This is what you need:

```
tmpfs /home/rkmax/Projects/webapp/app/cache tmpfs rw,size=500M,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0
```